# list comprehension of a nested for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, nested-loops

Unable to transform the following nested for loop to a list comprehension:

```
for row in rows:
    elements = row.strip().split('\t')
    for element in elements:
        print(element)
```

Input Data is tab delimited:

```
ola    olb    olc    old
ole    olf    olg    olh
oli    olj    olk    olk
oll    olm    oln    ooo
```

Desired Output:

```
ola
olb    
olc    
old
ole    
olf    
olg    
olh
oli    
olj    
olk    
olk
oll    
olm    
oln    
ooo
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flattening a shallow list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
with open('tabdelim.txt') as rows:
    lstcmp = [item for row in rows for item in row.strip().split('\t')]
    print('\n'.join(lstcmp))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum([row.strip().split('\t') for row in rows],[])
```

The builtin `sum` is very useful for flattening a list of lists.